# Swiper Js styles take time to load after page refresh in Next JS. Swiper slides are stretched till Next Js loads style. How to fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, swiper.js

I have Next 14.0.3 app with tailwind CSS. I installed swiper JS of version 11.0.5 with npm. Problem is when I reload page, swiper styles take 1 or 2 seconds to load. Swiper slides become fully stretched till Next Js loads swiper styles. Here is gif for better understanding: https://gyazo.com/5ba13d4a8eed7407cb124f2179309bb6.

Thanks in advance for any help.

My Swiper Component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { Navigation, Pagination } from "swiper/modules";

import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/pagination";

function SliderComp() {
  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <Swiper
        modules={[Navigation, Pagination]}
        spaceBetween={10}
        slidesPerView={3}
        grabCursor={true}
        navigation
        pagination={{ clickable: true }}
      >
        <SwiperSlide className="bg-sky-200 min-h-[300px]">Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide className="bg-sky-200 min-h-[300px]">Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide className="bg-sky-200 min-h-[300px]">Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide className="bg-sky-200 min-h-[300px]">Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SliderComp;
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "piuwee",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "antd": "^5.12.1",
    "next": "14.0.3",
    "node": "^18.14.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-animation-on-scroll": "^5.1.0",
    "react-compare-slider": "^3.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-fast-marquee": "^1.6.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.12.0",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-timer-hook": "^3.0.7",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "swiper": "^11.0.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's fixing this issue:

```
const initialTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light';
```

Just add this line of code and it will fix this issue. You don't have to use this initialTheme constant anywhere. I don't have an answer how this fixes swiper JS issue and what this has to do with swiper, but its fixing this issue.
If you have any idea how this works, your explanation is welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

This Works for me.

```
 const initialTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme') || 'light';
```

Comment: could you please explain why your code works, what it does, give it a little background?